# About Raw file format of Hasselblad H5D

Tags: raw, reverse-engineering, file-format, medium-format, hasselblad

We have a very good image manager which reads the Hasselblad H4D raw files and I want to ask some questions:

1. Does someone know if the RAW format of Hassy H5D is the same with the H4D? IOW, if we can open the H4D's raw files we will be able to open also the raw files from H5D?
2. Can someone post a raw sample originated from Hassy H5D (any photo will do, including one of a wall) together with a small jpeg/tiff/png in order to see how the raw must appear on the screen?

Comment: Which back(s)? It's the backs that matter, not the camera. BTW, the sample file downloads on the Hasselblad site(s) all say "H4D", but are from each of the various backs.

Comment: We're probably going to ASSUME Its the Hassel-back.

Comment: Yes, of course. It is/I'm speaking about the Hasselblad back. The default back which comes with H5D. Also, the samples from Hassy's site are tiffs not RAW.

Comment: It's not about the branding, it's about the *back*. There are 5 different Hasselblad backs specifically for the H5 (40MP crop CCD, 50MP and 60MP "conventional" full-frame CCD, 200MS, and a 50MP CMOS). The H4D had a similar-sized assortment of backs available (31, 40 and 50 "conventional", 50MS).

Answer (score 1):

Very, unlikely, unfortunately, without a update to your image manager.

If the chips are of different generations or types (CMOS vs CCD), the data is typically recorded with different RGB primaries, mask pixels and other data.  If the chips are the same, manufacturers still sometimes make changes in how the sensor is used to improve noise quality, or some of the recorded data to tweak color response.  This is typically different enough to warrant a "version number" change in the file format to indicate to raw readers that this file format is updated.

In short, you should expect your image manager to balk.

One way to know for sure is to try one from the back you are interested in.  Ask if someone would mind posting one for you over at [luminous-landscape](http://www.luminous-landscape.com/forum/index.php?board=16.0)'s or [GetDPI](http://www.getdpi.com/forum/medium-format-systems-digital-backs/)'s medium format forums.  I'm certain someone will provide you with a sample raw file for you to test.

Hope that helps,
-bRad